# More terse error handling in Go

Tags: error-handling, exception, go

How do I handle a lot of errors in Go?

I look at my code and find that it is full of error handlers:

```
err = result.Scan(&bot.BID, &bot.LANGUAGE, &bot.SOURCE)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("result.Scan: %v", err)
    return
}

fileName, err := copySourceToTemporaryFile(bot)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("copySourceToTemporaryFile: %v", err)
    return
}
...
```

And a lot of lines look like:

```
// do something
// handle error
// handle error
// handle error

// do something 2
// handle error
// handle error
// handle error
```

Can I create a default handler that prints an error and stops processing, or at least move out this "error-handler-garbage" out of my code logic?

Comment: It looks ugly at first (and later on), but I happen to like the kind of error catching. It really makes me think: "what should I do in this case? Should I crash (fatal), should I keep on going with some other method/default or should I ask the user". If you do a `log.Fatalf()` anyway, you could define a method `CrashIfErr(err error)` whith a simple call to `log.Fatalf()`. BTW: there is no need for a `return`  after a `log.Fatalf()`.

Answer (score 5):

That reminds me of the recent [Errors are values](https://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values) by Rob Pike, as well as [Mr. Rob Pike taught me about practice of error handling in Go at GoCon 2014](http://vimeo.com/113825668)

> The key lesson, however, is that errors are values and the full power of the Go programming language is available for processing them.
>
> It's worth stressing that whatever the design, it's critical that the program check the errors however they are exposed. The discussion here is not about how to avoid checking errors, it's about using the language to handle errors with grace.

One technique was to define an object called an `errWriter`:

```
type errWriter struct {
    w   io.Writer
    err error
}
```

> The `write` method calls the Write method of the underlying `Writer` and records the first error for future reference:

```
func (ew *errWriter) write(buf []byte) {
    if ew.err != nil {
        return
    }
    _, ew.err = ew.w.Write(buf)
}
```

> As soon as an error occurs, the `write` method becomes a no-op but the `error` value is saved.
>
> Given the `errWriter` type and its write method, the code above can be refactored:

```
ew := &errWriter{w: fd}
ew.write(p0[a:b])
ew.write(p1[c:d])
ew.write(p2[e:f])
// and so on
if ew.err != nil {
    return ew.err
}
```

Comment: I read that before. What if methods that i call returns not only errors but structs of different types?

Answer (score 1):

If the `error` is "real", you should (have to) handle it if you don't want unexpected panics at runtime.

To supplement VonC's answer about the `errWriter` technique, there are more cases where you can reduce error handling code:

These are the cases when you know that even though a function or method *may* return an `error`, it *will not* (e.g. you're supplying the parameters from source code which you know will work). In these cases you (or the author of the library) can provide *helper* functions (or methods) which do not return the `error` but raise a runtime panic if it still occurs.

Great examples of these are the [`template`](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) and [`regexp`](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/) packages: if you provide a valid template or regexp at compile time, you can be sure they can always be parsed without errors at runtime. For this reason the `template` package provides the [`Must(t *Template, err error) *Template`](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Must) function and the `regexp` package provides the [`MustCompile(str string) *Regexp`](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#MustCompile) function: they don't return `error`s because their intended use is where the input is guaranteed to be valid.

Examples:

```
// "text" is a valid template, parsing it will not fail
var t = template.Must(template.New("name").Parse("text"))

// `^[a-z]+\[[0-9]+\]$` is a valid regexp, always compiles
var validID = regexp.MustCompile(`^[a-z]+\[[0-9]+\]$`)
```

Comment: I like the `Mustxxx` approach, which can simplify the error management and clarify the expectation. +1