# Pretty boring to handle error

Tags: go

I have struct that have a method that serve the response.

```
type ctrl struct {
    *base.AjaxCtrl
    file ini.File
}

func (rcv *ctrl) getVar() string {
    return mux.Vars(rcv.Req)["location"]
}

func (rcv *ctrl) getFile() string {
    return location.JoinPaths(folder, rcv.getVar()+ext)
}

func (rcv *ctrl) upload() {
    file, err := ini.LoadFile(rcv.getFile())
    if err != nil {
        rcv.AddErr("TextError", err.Error())
        return
    }
    rcv.file = file
}

// Convert text to json structure
func (rcv *ctrl) convertToJson() string {
    js, err := json.Marshal(rcv.file.Section("text/signup"))
    if err != nil {
        rcv.AddErr("ConvertError", err.Error())
        return ""
    }
    return string(js)
}

func (rcv *ctrl) serveHttp() (types.SuccsJSON, types.ErrorsJSON) {

    rcv.upload()
    if rcv.AnyErrors() {
        return nil, rcv.Errs
    }

    str := rcv.convertToJson()
    if rcv.AnyErrors() {
        return nil, rcv.Errs
    }
    return c.Sucss, nil
}
```

The method serveHttp() handle the response to client. As you can see, I am handling the error with the method AnyError() everytime. I find this way is pretty boring and maybe wrong design.
Would it be better to throw a panic instead of error handling?

```
func (rcv *ctrl) upload() {
    file, err := ini.LoadFile(rcv.getFile())
    if err != nil {
        rcv.AddErr("TextError", err.Error())
        panic()
    }
    rcv.file = file
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error handling in Go language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409118/error-handling-in-go-language)

Comment: I abandoned GoLang because GoLang abandoned exceptions.

Comment: why? Golang is such as nice language.

Comment: I don't want to start a language war here - I agree GoLang is a **very** nice language - much to recommend it. I just cannot get comfortable with a language that does support exceptions, as stated, and as illustrated by your question (and numerous similar questions here) and the answers you received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it would not be better. Checking your errors is not bad design in Go. Panicking when there is no reason to do so, on the other hand, *is* bad design, because it's harder to test and debug.

[The Go Wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#dont-panic) explicitly discourages the use of `panic` outside of truly exceptional cases, when the error is unrecoverable and state of the program can't be fixed.