# How can I further my understanding of why Go handles errors the way it does?

Tags: go

I have Googled "Golang errors", "Go error handling", "Go errors" and "Go error verbose" to see what other people say on the subject, and also to read on some tutorials online.

I have also watched YouTube videos like these: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ph4eYD7Bgek

But I still can not understand why I have to add these lines after everything I do:

```
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Why does this not happen automatically? And I still cannot understand why this way is better than try, catch. I come from a PHP background, and in PHP, I almost never did error checking, every time something went wrong it logged stuff automatically, so why do I have to this manually on Go? What are the benefits? I really want to "Go" 100% about learning this language, but it feels so wrong to write the same code over and over again. It goes against what I have learned about programming, to not repeat yourself.

How can I understand this more? What is the reason and benefits of this? Maybe I would understand if someone came with examples of some situations why this way of handling error is the best way, and not try catch, and this way is better than not checking at all, like I did in PHP.

And I have already read on the official website of Go. And various other tutorials online such as:

https://gobyexample.com/

Video tutorial by Oreilly.

Video tutorial from Pluralsight.

Comment: "go programming language errors" brought up this blog: https://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values

Comment: Not a very good topic here. It's purely a design decision. It is subjective value that some developers hold. It is reflected in the language design. Joel Spolsky has a good blog on the topic and if you watch early presentations about Go done by Robert Pike he touches on it as well.

Comment: I understand your concern but it is impossible to answer your "question" and be in a line with stackoverflow guidelines. It is just too subjective. What I propose instead is for you is to summarize 5-7 major points "why it is good" from the tutorials you had read and watch and write down why you disagree.

Comment: Basically, the starting point is incorrect. "why I have to add these lines after everything I do" - no, you have not. Nobody enforces you to write them if you are not interested in the result. If you do, write them. But you are interested, right?

Comment: "[…] add these lines[…] Why does this not happen automatically?" Because it's neither sufficient (you just continue on after printing) nor the only thing wanted (outside of `main` I rarely want to print errors).

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted this to be a comment, but there are too many links:

[Blog post: Error handling and Go](http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go)

[Effective Go: Errors](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#errors)

[SO Answer: Error returns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30178766/1705598)

[SO Question: Go — handling multiple errors elegantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397419/go-handling-multiple-errors-elegantly)

[SO Question: More terse error handling in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409118/more-terse-error-handling-in-go)

[Blog post: Errors are values](https://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values)

[Code Review Question: A minimal version control system](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100525/a-minimal-version-control-system)

Function that returns an "error handler" function with context:

```
func ger(ctxt string) func(string, error) error {
    return func(msg string, err error) error {
        return fmt.Errorf("%s : %s : %v", ctxt, msg, err)
    }
}

// And using it:
er := ger("Handling cmd")
er("Add", err)
```

...the list goes on, use Google and SO search.

Comment: Thank you I will read further.