# Handling Aerospike library errors in Go Lang

Tags: go, error-handling, aerospike

I am quite new to Go Lang development. Recently I am using Aerospike Go client to getObject

```
err = aer.AeroDB.getObject(nil, key, Record)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

now the above error exposes only one method `Error()` which returns a string. I need to handle each type of errors differently. How do I do this, as there are no error codes returned. Do I do string matching to get the relevant type?

**SOLUTION:** Answer and comments below helped me to find an exact answer. I will share it here with the rest. Aerospike libraries export `AerospikeError` struct. Now, error could be nil or `AerospikeError` `struct`. Following code did the work.

```
import (
  "errors"
  "fmt"
  aerospike "github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go"
  "github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/types"
 )

type ArDB struct {
  Host   string
  Port   int
  AeroDB *aerospike.Client
}

ArErr, failed := aer.AeroDB.GetObject(nil, key, Record).(types.AerospikeError)
if failed {
    if ArErr.ResultCode() == types.KEY_NOT_FOUND_ERROR {
        //Key is not present, create new data
        Record = NewAudienceRecord()
    } else {
        //Handle other errors!
    }
}
```

Comment: Related / possible duplicates: [Does go have standard Err variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177860/does-go-have-standard-err-variables); and [many links posted in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32080378/1705598).

Comment: @icza so basically I have to rely on the type of struct the API provider is providing for error handling. If they don't provide any intelligible errors errors(as in this case) what are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function returns errors which are actually of different type, then you should use [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements):

```
switch err.(type) {
case Error1:
    fmt.Println("Error1", err)
case Error2:
    fmt.Println("Error2", err)
default:
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

But if the errors are of same type then you have to see does the package export some "common errors" as variables, so that you can check against those:

```
if err == aer.Error1 {
   // do something specific to Error1
}
```

Comment: For me all the errors are of AerespikeError type. In general if API exposes different struct for different types of error this would help.

Comment: Then you have to see does the package export some error variables you can compare the `err` against.

Comment: Just found that they have exported error codes. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Aerospike Go client dev here. In my experience, the concise conditional typecast shown below is more readable, albeit being the same as your own:

```
if ae, ok := err.(AerospikeError); ok {
    println(ae.ResultCode())
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly concise. I am a total noob in Go.